Custom Scrollbar using div
So what i`m trying to achieve is custom scrollbar with same behavior as default one, but this scrollbar should not take space at all, so z-index and position absolute.
but i'm not sure how to implement it so it will display scroll progress as default one
so i have this template


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const scrollContainer = document.querySelector('.scroll');
  const customScrollbar = document.querySelector('.scrollbar');



  scrollContainer.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    const scrollHeight = scrollContainer.scrollHeight - scrollContainer.clientHeight;
    console.log(scrollContainer.scrollTop);
    const scrollTop = scrollContainer.scrollTop;
    const scrollPercentage = (scrollTop / scrollHeight) * 100;


    customScrollbar.style.top = `${scrollPercentage}%`;
  });
});
.scroll {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.scrollbar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: red;
}

.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.scroll {
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.scroll::-ms-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="scrollbar"></div>
    <a>bbbbb</a>
    <a>bbbbb</a>
    <a>bbbbb</a>
    <a>bbbbb</a>
    <a>bbbbb</a>
    <a>bbbbb</a>
    <a>bbbbb</a>
    <a>bbbbb</a>
    <a>aaaaa</a>
    <a>bbbbb</a>
    <a>bbbbb</a>
    <a>bbbbb</a>
    <a>bbbbb</a>
    <a>bbbbb</a>
    <a>bbbbb</a>
    <a>bbbbb</a>
    <a>bbbbb</a>
    <a>bbbbb</a>
    <a>bbbbb</a>
    <a>bbbbb</a>
    <a>bbbbb</a>
    <a>bbbbb</a>
    <a>bbbbb</a>
    <a>bbbbb</a>

  </div>
</body>

</html>



ps: overflow:overlay; is not possible for me because i'm making desktop app and this feature there is not supported at all, and custom js libraries like overlay-scrollbars are not suitable for me too i guess, but feel free to provide some ideas or code :)
